# lapply when both list elements their names are arguments of the function

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

My toy dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(
  value = sample(1:10),
  class = sample(c("a","b"), 20, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I split my data frame up by values of 'class' and put them in a list where each list element is named after its class:

```
l <- dlply(d, .(class), function(x)return(x))
```

Then I want to lapply over each class and make a histogram. Note that I do NOT want a facet. I want as many individual files saved as classes. So I define a function doPlots that makes histograms, then ggsaves them (as a_hist.png and b_hist.png, in this example):

```
doPlots <- function(d, name){
  g <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x=value)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
  ggsave(filename=paste(name,"hist.png",sep="_"))
}
```

However, when I lapply:

```
lapply(l, FUN=doPlots, name=names(l))
```

I get Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `lapply(l, function(x) doPlots(x,names(x)))`.  Your `names(l)` is the entire vector of names of the list `l`, rather than just the one you want for each iteration.

Comment: that makes sense (thank you!) but i still get the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code, one is that you are passing the entire vector of names to the function. Second, you have not added a plot to save to the `ggsave` function. You can use `mapply` to iterate over two or more lists.

```
doPlots <- function(d, name){
  g <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x=value)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
  ggsave(filename=paste(name, "hist.png", sep="_"), g)
}

mapply(doPlots, l, names(l))
```

Comment: the default is for ggsave to use the last plot, so that part is not necessary I believe. but thank you, using mapply worked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `by` which slices a dataframe by factor levels into a list of elements. You can even pass your user-defined function into it all in one call:

```
dlist <- by(d, d$class, FUN=function(i) {      
             name <- max(as.character(i$class))
             doPlots(i, name)      
         })
```